# DATA & VOICE VLAN ROUTING BETWEEN 2 ROUTERS

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, cisco-asa, voice

Good Afternoon All-

I would appreciate a little help with a current issue I am facing...
I can ping all Network Segments, all Routers, all Switches, and all Servers on the network.

****PROBLEM IS:** I CAN'T PING OR ACCESS THE IP PHONES CONNECTED TO DIRECTLY TO PoE SW3!!!
HOWEVER, IF I MOVE THE IP OF SW3 FROM VLAN 1 TO VLAN 200 WHICH IS ALSO CONFIGURED AS THE VOICE VLAN ON SW3 AND THE IP PHONES, I CAN NOW PING SUCCESSFULLY FROM THE SWITCH TO THE PHONE ONLY!!! BUT NOT THE REST OF THE NETWORK DEVICES...**

THANK YOU VERY MUCH IN ADVANCE FOR YOUR ASSISTANCE!!!

I have a Data and a Voice Networks with VLANS configured on all Routers and Switches as well as svi on the ASA Firewall, please see below my current HW Environment:

(1) Cisco ASA 5520 (2) Cisco 1900 Routers (4) Cisco SG300 L3 Switches
**VLAN 1 DATA
VLAN 200 VOICE**

CISCO ASA
Gi0/0 | ISP NETWORK | CONNECTED TO ISP ROUTER
Gi0/1 | BACK-BONE NETWORK | CONNECTED TO CORE SW2
Gi0/2 | R2 NETWORK 10.10.20.250 | CONNECTED TO R2 VOICE | VLAN 2
Gi0/3 | R1 NETWORK 10.10.70.250 | CONNECTED TO R1 DATA | VLAN 1

CISCO R1
Gi0/0 | ASA | CONNECTED TO ASA Gi0/3 | 10 NETWORK | 10.10.70.1
Gi0/1 | DATA LAN 192.168.7.1 | SW1
SVI FOR VLAN 1 WITH IP 192.168.7.1
SVI FOR VLAN 200 UNASSIGNED (NO IP ADDRESS)

CISCO R2
Gi0/0 | ASA | CONNECTED TO ASA Gi0/2 | 10 NETWORK | 10.10.20.1
Gi0/1 | VOICE LAN 192.168.200.1 | SW3
SVI FOR VLAN 1 UNASSIGNED (NO IP ADDRESS)
SVI FOR VLAN 200 WITH IP 192.168.200.1

CISCO SW1 L3 | ALL SERVERS LIVE HERE
Gi0/25 | **VLAN 1** | IP ADD 192.168.7.254 CONNECTED TO R1 Gi0/1
Gi0/26 | UPLINK TO CORE SW2
Gi0/27 | UPLINK TO VOICE SW3

CISCO CORE SW2 L3 | **NETWORK 1** **NETWORK 2** **NETWORK 10** CONNECTED HERE
Gi0/25 | **VLAN 1** | IP ADD 192.168.7.249 CONNECTED TO R1 Gi0/1
Gi0/26 | UPLINK TO CORE SW2
Gi0/27 | UPLINK TO VOICE SW3
Gi0/28 | UPLINK TO SW4

CISCO VOICE SW3 L3 | **NETWORK 200** IP PHONES CONNECTED HERE
Gi0/25 | **VLAN 1** | IP ADD 192.168.200.248 CONNECTED TO R2 Gi0/1
Gi0/26 | UPLINK TO CORE SW2
Gi0/27 | UPLINK TO VOICE SW1

CISCO SECURITY CAMS SW4 L3 | **NETWORK 1** IP CAMERAS CONNECTED HERE
Gi0/25 | **VLAN 1** | IP ADD 192.168.7.246 UPLINK TO SW2
Gi0/26 | UPLINK TO  SW1
Gi0/27 | UPLINK TO VOICE SW3

[image: TOPOLOGY]

Comment: You'll need to provide sanitized configs from all of the relevant network devices in the path.

Comment: We cannot tell, but you may not have the switch default gateway set, jor it could be a routing problem, and we need the full configurations of the network devices.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses, I will gather all the configs and post them tomorrow morning...

Comment: Please also remove the SHOUTING from your question. It's rude.

Comment: @Zac67 LOL Does it hurt your virtual ears?